# How to turn the screen on?

Tags: android, screen

*DUPLICATE WARNING: this problem is for both services and frontends, there are some similar threads but focused on GUI approaches.*

### Problem

Starting from whatever the state is (music playing in the background, screen on (sic!), screen off, phone locked, phone unlocked, and so on) I would like to change only one thing in the state -- turn the screen on. Nothing else should change.

### Attempts

To start from some known state I lock the phone and turn the screen off:

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager)context
                .getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
dpm.lockNow();
```

so from now on, turning on screen would mean actually displaying the keyguard. I try to do this with:

- forcing `userActivity` -- nothing happens at all
- various combinations of wake locks -- either wake is too weak (like `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` -- nothing happens) or it triggers screen on, but as long as I keep the lock. Once I release it the screen goes back to off state (despite I have `ON_AFTER_RELEASE` set); minor problem is I have to acquire wake lock with some delay after `lockNow` because otherwise `lockNow` would be simply canceled

### Workaround

This is almost copy&paste from [Changing the Screen Brightness System Setting Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708692/changing-the-screen-brightness-system-setting-android/9848456#9848456) by 
[Anton Cherkashyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204377/anton-cherkashyn)

You need to add fake activity which triggers screen on:

```
public class DummyBrightnessActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);            
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        
        //this next line is very important, you need to finish your activity with slight delay
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
             public void run() { 
                 DummyBrightnessActivity.this.finish();
                 } },0);
    }

}
```

Next you have to launch this activity (in my case it is usually non-activity, thus option for background):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DummyBrightnessActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        context.startActivity(intent);
        } },500);
```

And you have to notify your app about this fake activity in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".DummyBrightnessActivity"
          android:excludeFromRecents="true"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
          android:taskAffinity="com.antonc.phone_schedule.Dummy">
</activity>
```

(above -- it is placed in the main namespace of my app).

The problem is it is lengthy and not reliably -- the first delay (in activity) works for 0 quite fine, but the second... different story, when I did some logging "350" were enough, but once I dropped logging (thus execution was tad faster) I had to increase the value.

So now face the fact that you have "screenOn" feature, but it won't work, because some user will buy faster phone ;-)

Anyway, still looking for something better...

Comment: Have you tried something like the answer from this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712849/how-do-i-keep-the-screen-on-in-my-app

Comment: @ziziana, as I wrote at the beginning, I tried combinations of wake locks -- they don't work as "switchScreenOn". They are either ignored or keep screen in "on" state.

Answer (score 0):

Hope bellow sample to help you, do not forget to release your wakelock!

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "wakelock_event_name");

wl.acquire();
 // Your Code
wl.release()
```

also you can use 
    // when - time **when** this happens SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    pm.userActivity(**when**, true/false)