# Change brightness on Notification

Tags: android, notifications, brightness

Code for notification:

```
mNotificationManager = 
             (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final Notification notifyDetails = 
            new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"New Alert, Click Me!",System.currentTimeMillis());
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
      notifyDetails.
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Notification Details...";

    CharSequence contentText = "Browse Android Official Site by clicking me";
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.android.com"));

    PendingIntent intent1 = 
          PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, 
          notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent1);
    mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
```

My notification works fine, what I want to happen is the screen brightness to increase to a certain value when the notification pops up.

I used Eclipse's auto complete feature to find the right function, but none work. I also searched quite a bit, no luck.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar brightness problem some time ago. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708692/changing-the-screen-brightness-system-setting-android/9848456#9848456). It should point you in the right direction.

Add this to your activity:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 255);//255 here is your brightness value, an integer that can be between 0 and 255.
float brightness = 1.0f; //Your desired brightness, float value between 0.0 and 1.0
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = brightness;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

and add this permission to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

I've just tested it and this code works on Android 4.1.

Comment: I don't want to change the brightness with a dummy activity. When my app receives a notification, I'd like the phone's brightness to go up.

Comment: So don't use the dummy activity part, just use the code that changes the brightness. It's in there. Or do you want me to copy-paste it in here for you?

Comment: Could you show me how I can change the brightness with the notification? With the code, that would be very helpful :)

Comment: I realized that's the brightness editing part. Should I call the notification after that?

Comment: Well, that depends on how you want to handle it. I would make it show the notification first and then change the brightness. But I suppose it would work equally well if you did it in reverse order.

Comment: The brightness isn't changing even though I called a notification.

Comment: Updated the answer once more. I tested this code and it works.

Comment: That is the code I'm using. I forgot tp mention the fact that I'm using a service. So, I want the brightness to update on notification. Do I have to call a dummy activity?

Comment: Yes, you have to use a dummy activity.