# Android: Cannot Call "BrightnessPreference" Class (from package com.android.settings)

Tags: android, android-intent, settings, brightness

In my app, when a button is clicked, I would like to `call the Brightness class` found in `Android system settings` (shown when the user navigates *Settings > Display > Brightness*).

I know that to call the `Display class` (on which the Brightness class is found) I can use the following code:

```
Intent brightness = new Intent();
brightness.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DisplaySettings");
startActivity(brightness);
```

So, it would seem intuitive that to call the Brightness class, one would substitute "BrightnessPreference" for "DisplaySettings" (since both are saved in the same location as seen at [this link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r2.1/com/android/settings/BrightnessPreference.java?av=f)) as follows:

```
Intent brightness = new Intent();
brightness.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.BrightnessPreference");
startActivity(brightness);
```

However, when I try to run this code on my emulator, `it force closes`.  Is there anything I'm not seeing, or is `calling BrightnessPreference` not possible for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BrightnessPreference extends `Preference` Class.

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html)

`Preference class provides the View to be displayed in the activity`

Where as what you are trying to do is open it as an activity using an intent, which according me is not possible.

You can set it programmatically as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9848456/983741)